# Implementing a category on all classes conforming to a protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols, scenekit

I have written a category on SCNRenderer that adds some camera utility methods. Those same methods would be equally useful to SCNView and SCNLayer. All three of the classes to which this category would be relevant conform to SCNSceneRenderer. Is it possible to write a category that applies not to a specific class, but to all classes that conform to a particular protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be to write some utility functions that take an SCNSceneRenderer object:

```
void ABCDoSomethingUseful(id<SCNSceneRenderer> renderer)
{
   //...
}

void ABCDoSomethingElseUseful(id<SCNSceneRenderer> renderer)
{
   //...
}
```

If you want to use the method call syntax, or want to be able to override the implementation in subclasses, another option would be to implement the methods as a category on NSObject:

```
// This goes in a source file:

@interface NSObject (SCNSceneRendererConformance) <SCNSceneRenderer>
// Surpress compiler warnings about NSObject not responding to 
// SCNSceneRenderer's messages
@end

@implementation NSObject (MyCategory)

- (void)abc_doSomethingUseful
{
    //...
}


- (void)abc_doSomethingElseUseful
{
    //...
}

@end
```

then expose them in a protocol:

```
// This goes in a header file:

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)abc_doSomethingElseUseful;
- (void)abc_doSomethingUseful;
@end
```

and add an interface-only category for each class that conforms to SCNSceneRenderer declaring that it also conforms to your protocol:

```
// This also goes in a header file:

@interface SCNLayer (MyProtocolConformance) <MyProtocol>
@end

@interface SCNView (MyProtocolConformance) <MyProtocol>
@end
```

Comment: What I've done for now is just ignore the fact that this category would be useful for more than one class, and just implement it for SCNRenderer. I think the route of writing utility functions is probably the way to go. I'll probably make them class methods on some utility class.

Comment: Yeah... Looking back at the category on NSObject idea, it's a lot of weird for not much gain...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add category over a protocol, since protocol just defines interface not implementation. Whereas in category we need to implement as well.